# Should I update the Ubuntu release name for PPAs?

Tags: upgrade, apt, ppa, repository

Does it matter that I have files like webupd8team-jupiter-precise.list in my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder if I'm using raring? Should I update the sources inside to say raring instead of precise or quantal? I'm conflicted on what to do, because if I had added the repos today with `add-apt-repository` then the release names would have been up to date. But if updating them was fine, then that should have happened on the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

if the repo has a raring source switch to it, for getdeb & playdeb you should use quantal since there is no raring yet
edit the inside of the file the file name is not important

Comment: How am I supposed to know if a repo has a source available? For example, here is the repo I mentioned in the question: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter

Does this also mean that add-apt-repository might add the wrong source for the ppa, since it always adds the one you're on?

Comment: click the published in drop down, the newest in there is quantal right now, you can edit it in software sources